# Graphic problem ATI Radeon HD7770

Tags: debian, ati

My OS (resembling Ubuntu 12) is having a graphical issue. An app `"ATI binary X.Org driver"` when not installed makes the graphics very laggy and slow; while I can take screenshots. When installed, there are a few glitches in minimized windows and I can't take screen shots. It is also always showing the same background. I have `ATI Radeon HD7770` graphics card.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you was installed the `ATI Catalyst driver` please remove it

and follow this guide for installing the `ATI open source driver`

[How do I install the X.org Radeon/ATI driver?](https://askubuntu.com/a/225563/358332)

> some ATI graphic devices are multi-gpu and you should enable
>   `switchable graphic mode` in your system bios